# Install R packages on Ubuntu error

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I have R and Rstudio installed on an Ubuntu server (14), when I tried to install packages, I get these errors:

```
>install.packages("nnet")
    Installing package into ‘/home/zhge/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    --2015-09-08 02:43:31--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/nnet_7.3-11.tar.gz Resolving
    cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.230.140.42 Connecting to
    cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.230.140.42|:443... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 28455 (28K)
    [application/x-gzip] Saving to:
    ‘/tmp/RtmpBT7yHE/downloaded_packages/nnet_7.3-11.tar.gz’

         0K .......... .......... .......                         100% 1.20M=0.02s

    2015-09-08 02:43:31 (1.20 MB/s) -
    ‘/tmp/RtmpBT7yHE/downloaded_packages/nnet_7.3-11.tar.gz’ saved
    [28455/28455]

    /usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 140: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: Permission denied
    /usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 236: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: Permission denied
    Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection Calls:
    <Anonymous> -> sub -> grep -> readLines -> file In addition: Warning
    message: In file(con, "r") :   cannot open file
    '/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf': Permission denied Warning in
    install.packages :   installation of package ‘nnet’ had non-zero exit
    status

    The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpBT7yHE/downloaded_packages’
```

UPDATE:
It was just permission issue, all i needed is just:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 0777 /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths
```

and for the other directories: /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf and /usr/lib/R/bin/. I never had this issue before, so it didn't come to me as the problem immediately.

Comment: I seriously doubt that your Ubuntu server has version 0.14. Also, please add the *complete* command you use to install the packages, plus information about the account you're using (I guess it's zhge, but guessing is not knowing).

Comment: The error is pretty clear. For some (strange) reason, your user is not allowed to read the file `/usr/lib/R/bin/R`. You can verify this with `ls /usr/lib/R/bin/R -lrt` from command line. Why you can't, I don't know.

Comment: updated the post with the solution, sorry for wasting your time